# Databinding Command for a Button inside a DockPanel not working when a DockPanel Visibility property is set

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind Button Command property to ICommand property from a ViewModel (Button placed inside a DockPanel). It worked fine before I set Visibility property of a DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel  Grid.Row="1">
     <Button Content="Read" Command="{Binding ButtonBeginReadCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
     <Button Content="Write" Command="{Binding ButtonBeginWriteCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
</DockPanel>
```

But after adding Visibility property to the DockPanel, things go strange (now button is not clickable, but visibility works fine):

```
<DockPanel  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsFilenameCorrect, Converter={StaticResource HiddenIfFalse}}">
     <Button Content="Read" Command="{Binding ButtonBeginReadCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
     <Button Content="Write" Command="{Binding ButtonBeginWriteCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
</DockPanel>
```

I also tried to set RelativeSource for a Button Command, but it did not help:

```
<DockPanel  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsFilenameCorrect, Converter={StaticResource HiddenIfFalse}}">
     <Button Content="Read" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonBeginReadCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
     <Button Content="Write" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonBeginWriteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
</DockPanel>
```

DataContext set as:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

There is part of the MainWindowViewModel class. I used a custom AsyncCommand implementation (can't remember where I found it):

```
...
public ICommand ButtonBeginReadCommand { get; private set; }
public MainWindowViewModel() {
...
ButtonBeginReadCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () =>
        {

            await Task.Delay(300);
            Monitor.Enter(_locker);
            ...
            Monitor.Exit(_locker);
        });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Setting the `Visiblity` property will not affect your binding. The code that you have shared works fine for me. Can u share more code?

Comment: Sorry, I used CustomBoolToVis Converter, then tried to set Visibility="Visible" - the same effect. Question updated, part of MainWindowViewModel added.

Comment: Not sure why you are initializing the `ButtonBeginRead` property? You should be initializing the `ButtonBeginReadCommand` property. Check my sample code.

Comment: ButtonBeginRead <= It's just a typo.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the inbuilt `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

I am sharing the sample code. You might have to change the namespace to get it working.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DockPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:DockPanel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:VM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsFilenameCorrect, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Button Content="Read" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonBeginReadCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        <Button Content="Write" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonBeginWriteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DockPanel
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class VM
    {
        public bool IsFilenameCorrect { get; set; }
        public ICommand ButtonBeginReadCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ButtonBeginWriteCommand { get; set; }
        private object _locker = new object();

        public VM()
        {

            IsFilenameCorrect = true;
            ButtonBeginReadCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () =>
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(300);
                        Monitor.Enter(_locker);
                        MessageBox.Show("Read");
                        Monitor.Exit(_locker);
                    });

            ButtonBeginWriteCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(300);
                Monitor.Enter(_locker);
                MessageBox.Show("Write");
                Monitor.Exit(_locker);
            });
        }
    }

    public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
    {
        Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
    }

    public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
    {
        public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
        public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }

    public class AsyncCommand : AsyncCommandBase
    {
        private readonly Func<Task> _command;
        public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> command)
        {
            _command = command;
        }
        public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public override Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
        {
            return _command();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It helped me a lot, thanks. Actually, problem was in the custom BooleanToVisibilityConverter [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/285358/All-purpose-Boolean-to-Visibility-Converter). I don't know why it broke binding process. Can you point to this problem in your answer, then I edit my question and mark the answer as accepted? Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Happy that I could help you. I have changed the answer.